# Centering an absolutely positioned element

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have an element containing two images, one layered on top of the other. The containing element is floated left and in a row of three. I have used a jQuery fix to center the images into its element. I had to use jQuery as it is a responsive design so the image changes size. This all works great apart from on some mobile devices. The image width doesn't seem to be calculated until a random element is pressed? I hope this makes sense. The URL is mooble.co.uk and its the left, larger image down the page.

**EDIT

Sorry I didn't make it clear that, the solution I have used works fine but on mobile devices the width and left margin doesn't seem to be calculated on load? After maybe 20 seconds it seems to pop into position.

EDIT**

```
<div class="g1" id="mass">
<p><span class="highlight"></span></p>
<div id="mass-cont">

<img class="bottom" src="images/mass.png" />
<img class="top" src="images/no-mass.png" />


</div>

</div>
```

css

```
#mass{position:relative;}
#mass-cont{}
#mass img{position:absolute;left:50%;}
#mass img{transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;display:block;}
#mass img.top:hover{opacity:0;}
```

JS

```
//Functions
function setImageHeight(){

var imageSize = $('.bottom').height();
$('#mass-cont').height(imageSize);

var imageWidth = $('.bottom').width();
var position = imageWidth / 2;

$('#mass-cont > img').css('margin-left' , '-'+ position + 'px');

}

//Load Document
$(document).ready(function() {

//Set image height

$('.bottom').load(function(){

setImageHeight();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

setImageHeight();


});

});
```

Comment: try this : 1) http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/ 2) http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it based on the window width in the past and setting the left margin of the element.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 setPosition();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
 setPosition();
});

function setPosition(){
var WindowWidth = $(window).width();
var BottomWidth = 300; //The width of bottom
Left Position = (WindowWidth - BottomWidth) / 2;
$(".bottom").css("margin-left", BottomWidth + "px");
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The solution I used works the same as yours, but mobile devices don't seem to calculate everything on load?

Comment: Oh I see for mobile widths I think you have to use something like this. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
left = ($("#mass-cont").width() - $(".bottom").width()) / 2;
$(".bottom").css("left", left)
```